# Using Marshal to send a JAXB object with the XML having no whitespaces (marshalSendAndReceive)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to use marshalSendAndReceive in order to convert my JaxB object to XML and send a request to an endpoint. However, the issue is I have quite a large XML which is causing failures in some cases.

To get around it, I want to get rid of the "pretty" XML format which I know you can do if you control the marshaller by setting the second parameter to false.

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);
```

This will cause the XML from looking like

```
<dog>0.0</dog>
<cat>0.0</cat>
```

to this

```
<dog>0.0</dog><cat>0.0</cat>
```

My problem is I need to use the marshalSendAndReceive function call, which will create the marshaller on its own in the library and therefore i cant modify the properties. Does anyone have any ways to get around this?

Comment: A WebServiceTemplate can be created [passing marshaler/unmarshaler as arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#WebServiceTemplate(org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller,%20org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller))

Comment: sorry, can you clarify on this and how it could be helpful?

Comment: instead of `WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();` which I assume you are using somehow, use the 2 args constructor passing marshaler/unmarshaler; `WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(mars, unmars)`. That way you can pass your custom marshaller  `mars.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);`

Comment: I see, do you know actually if the marshall used in "marshalSendAndReceive", is already formatted with false? I tried checking but im not sure what the default is. If thats the case, we wouldnt need to even make the change

Comment: Don't know really but you can [browse source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/main/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.java#L342) and find it out

Comment: I looked through it but dont see anywhere they are specifying the format. Also confused since in my example i use a "jaxb" marshaller but line 395 in the code you sent they use a normal spring marshaller so not sure if there is a difference. I would assume if they dont specifiy then it doesnt format but im not even sure how to test it because i cant throw in any logs. Any ideas?

Comment: Make your question a [mcve] so anyone helping has a clear idea of the issue. We've been guessing so far